# Replacement for Yahoo Finance API

Tags: api, finance

With Yahoo removing access to their Finance API in early November, I'm looking for an alternative to get information on financial quotes.

My only requirements:

- programmatic access (i.e. the service exposes web services or a REST API), and
- up-to-date information

I'm alright if the service is paid (free or ad-supported access would be alright as well).

Comment: Google Finance API? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-finance-apis